# How to include ignored files when using Publish tool in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, publish

I have a directory `/media/fonts` in my asp.net mvc project which contains fonts for my website. When I use the "Publish" tool in Visual Studio this folder is ignored even though it is included in my project. Other folders `/media/images` and `/media/css` are included just fine.

Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to not ignore this folder on publish?

Comment: Can you specify file types to include for publication?

Comment: .eot,.woff,.ttf,.svg Those are the file extensions in the fonts folder

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can fix this permanently by modifying the default Build Action for font file extensions (.eot, .ttf, etc)

http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx

The link has been assassinated by the cruel march of time, so here's a copy/paste of its contents:

The default build action of a file type can be configured in the registry. However, instead of hacking the registry manually, we use a much better approach: pkgdef files (a good article about pkgdef files). In essence, pkdef are configuration files similar to .reg files that define registry keys and values that are automatically merged into the correct location in the real registry. If the pkgfile is removed, the changes are automatically undone. Thus, you can safely modify the registry without the danger of breaking anything – or at least, it’s easy to undo the damage.

Finally, here’s an example of how to change the default build action of a file type:

```
[$RootKey$\Projects{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}\FileExtensions.spark]
"DefaultBuildAction"="Content"
```

The Guid in the key refers to project type. In this case, `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` means “C# projects”. A rather comprehensive list of project type guids can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs). Although it does not cover Visual Studio 2010 explicitly, the Guids apply to the current version as well. By the way, we can use C# as the project type here, because C# based MVC projects are in fact C# projects (and web application projects). For Visual Basic, you’d use `{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}` instead.

`$RootKey$` is an abstraction of the real registry key that Visual Studio stores the configuration under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config
```

(Note: Do not try to manually edit anything under this key as it can be overwritten at any time by Visual Studio).

The rest should be self explanatory: this option sets the default build action of `.spark` files to “Content”, so those files are included in the publishing process.

All you need to do now is to put this piece of text into a file with the extension pkgdef, put it somewhere under

```
%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
```

(on 64-bit systems) or

```
%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
```

(on 32-bit systems) and Visual Studio will load and apply the settings automatically the next time it starts. To undo the changes, simply remove the files.

Comment: Rock on! Thanks so much for this comment. I wish I could vote you up 2x

Comment: Does the default action only apply to files added after applying the .pkgdef files?

Comment: Yes - the default action is specifying what to put in the .csproj file for files of that type, when added. Files already added will already have their BuildAction set. Edit the .csproj file as a text file and take a look - this will become very clear once you do. It sounds like you need to change the BuildAction of a lot of files at once - find and replace while editing the .csproj as a text file shall set you free.

Comment: I'm on VS 2015 and tried this, but it didn't work. Also, my font files are already marked as Content.  I liked the solution though.

Comment: @WillStrohl This fix will work for 2010-2013. I don't currently use 2015 so can't test there. If you're sure it fails there might be worth contacting Microsoft about while they're active on 2015 dev.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Thanks for following up on the comment. This was actually my fault. The MSBuild file I had wasn't including the file extensions.

Comment: The link is broken. This is why it's a bad idea to post link-only answers.

Answer (score 44):

Select your font files and Change Build action as Content from Properties Window.

Comment: This fixes it in the immediate, but leaves you open to missing files in the future - see my answer for a permanent solution.

Comment: It looks like you may also need to set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".

Comment: I'm using 2015 and tried this, as well as the advice from @ChrisMoschini and set Copy Always ... font files are still ignored by MSBuild.

Comment: @WillStrohl I thought my font files were being ignored too after following the above steps. Turns out that if you use font files like .woff you need to specify the mimetype in the web.config:

<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

If you don't the files get published, but you'll still receive a 404.

P.S. Late to the party, but stumbled on this today and maybe it will help others.

Answer (score -2):

Visual Studio does publish font files. In a special case we renamed extensions from `.ttf` to `.jpg` and they got published.

Comment: Ugh. What an undesirable workaround. I am going to see if anyone else posts another solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I was not aware of correct way. Now by getting negative reputes know that changing build action does the work!