# Include in project function sets the Build Action for some files to None

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish

In Visual Studio 2010 when you do `Include in project` VS will set `Build Action` for some files to `Content` and for some to `None` (specifically the extensions that are apparently unknown to VS). I include public directories such as those containing `.ai` and `.pdf` files in the project because I later perform a publish via the `Publish` feature. The `Publish` feature will only copy those files that have `Build Action` set to `Content` to the output directory/web host.

The option to manually go over the files that were set `Build Action` to `None` is not applicable - impossible and time consuming.

I need to change the behaviour of the `Include in project` feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include ignored files when using Publish tool in VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455409/how-to-include-ignored-files-when-using-publish-tool-in-vs2010)

Comment: Chris Moschini has the solution to this.